# TypeScript: type pattern not matched when using keyof instead of literal

Tags: typescript

```
type a = { [K in keyof { "foo" }]: { foo: "bar" } extends { K } ? true : false }["foo"];
type b = { foo: "bar" } extends { "foo" } ? true : false;
```

`a` and `b` should both be type `true` according to my understanding, but `a` turns out to be `false`.
Could anyone help explain the reason? Or maybe it's a bug in TypeScript?
Note: tested under TypeScript 4.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've reported this problem as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46964) in TypeScript's official repository, and here's the reply from [*RyanCavanaugh*](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh), which solves this problem.

> ```
> type a = { foo: "bar" } extends { "foo" } ? true : false;
> type b = { [K in keyof { "foo" }]: { foo: "bar" } extends { K } ? true : false }["foo"];
> ```
>
> The type being resolved here (annotated for additional clarity) is
>
> ```
> { foo: "bar" } extends { K: any } ? true : false
> ```
>
> K in this position is a property name, not a reference to the key type. You could equally have written
>
> ```
> type a = { foo: "bar" } extends { "foo" } ? true : false;
> type b = { [K in keyof { "foo" }]: { foo: "bar" } extends { QQQ } ? true : false }["foo"];
> ```
>
> Which is clearly correctly `false`
>
> This is `true` as expected:
>
> ```
> type b = { [K in keyof { "foo": any }]: ({ foo: "bar" } extends Record<K, unknown> ? true : false) }["foo"];
> ```